# Find a full word with a substring from a text file in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am searching for a solution which will only give me the **full word as output** and *not the whole line*.

For example

FileName.txt contains in a single line as

```
ProductABC_Test.txt Productdef_Test.txt test.xml Productghi_Test.txt
```

anbcf

and I need to search `my.txt` file if it contains any `.xml` and if yes

then the batch should give me the **full name** i.e. `text.xml`

If My file content is

- ProductABC_Test.txt **test1.xml** Productdef_Test.txt **test2.xml**
  Productghi_Test.txt

How i can get those in to 2 different variables

thanks in Advance

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, providing a [mcve] by [edit]ing the question!

Comment: i need to extract the all the .xml values in to different variables which are present in that line of the .txt file.

Comment: did you follow the links I provided? did you even read my comment??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (filename.txt) do for %%b in (%%a) do if "%%~xb"==".xml" echo %%b
```

should yield the required result.

(read each line from the file, then examine each token - if the token is regarded as a filename and the extension is `.xml` then show that token.

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q50701268.txt"
SET "files="
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%filename1%) do for %%b in (%%a) do if "%%~xb"==".xml" CALL SET "files=%%files%% %%b"
ECHO %files%
SET "files="
SET /a fcnt=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%filename1%) do for %%b in (%%a) do if "%%~xb"==".xml" SET /a fcnt+=1&CALL SET "files%%fcnt%%=%%b"
SET files

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q50701268.txt` in my test directory `u:\sourcedir` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Two different methods for the `multiples files` extension.

The first provides a single variable containing a list of the names separated by spaces. It could of course be modified to any separator and possibly quoting the names if desired.

The second generates separate variables containing the names.

Comment: I need to set the result to a variable but If there are "two" or "three" such values of **.xml** in the line, how can i get the values in to 2 or 3  different variables?

Comment: What is the inner `for` loop for? why not using `%%~xa`?

Comment: @aschipfl: The outer loop reads the line(s) from the file. The inner loop processes the line read as space-separated elements.

Comment: Ah yes, I see, seems I misread the question and missed the point "in a single line"...

Comment: I tried the Second solution but i am getting this as my output D:\dev\FileCreator>kpk1.bat
ECHO is off.
Environment variable files not defined